# Subtract two dates columns in oracle

Tags: oracle

i have to subtract indate and upt from this query. i am a beginner.

```
select * from (
SELECT indate ,Max(TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) as upt
FROM ntlcrm.survey A
INNER JOIN survey_operations B
ON A.id = B.surveyid group by indate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Difference of two `DATE` datatype values results in number of days, so you'd just

```
select indate - datetime as result
from ...
```

In your case, that's still just

```
select indate - max(datetime) as result
from survey a join survey_operations b on b.surveyid = a.id
group by indate
```

---

If you stored any of these values as strings, you'll have to convert them to **date** datatype, not into (another) strings - which is what `to_char` in your query does.

For some more info, consider posting sample data and result you expect based on that data (but not as a comment - edit the question).

Comment: i want them in days

Comment: As I said: difference of two DATE datatype values **is** number of days between them. That can be a decimal number, if values contain time component. Re-read everything I said, please.